# Vert.x: Concurrency of some verticles in the same vertex

Tags: concurrency, reactive-programming, vert.x

I'm very new to vert.x and I have a very basic question: 
Let's say that a vertex includes some verticles. It's usually said that a vertex is single-threaded. Does it mean that if one verticle is being processed, then another verticle that **belongs to the same vertex** will have to wait until the first verticle ends, and only then it (the other verticle) will be able to start its work? I mean that there is no context switch between verticles in the same vertex.

Answer (score 0):

One application can have multiple verticles. Vert.x applications are event-driven, passing the events to *handlers*. Vert.x will call those handlers using a thread called the *event loop*.

Usually you don't block in a Vert.x application (and when you do it you correct it). The event loop then runs delivering events to different handlers in succession as they arrive, potentially delivering huge amounts of events in a short amount of time (like Node.js, for instance).

Vert.x can also work in a multi-core server with no effort. So instead of a single event loop, each Vert.x instance maintains several event loops. Keep in mind that, even though a Vert.x instance can maintain multiple event loops, **any particular handler will never be executed concurrently**, and in most cases (with the exception of *worker verticles*) will always be called using the exact same event loop.

I think that is the part you were looking for. You can read [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/) for more details.